# Magento 2 Overwriting Templates - Destination directory for template files

Tags: magento2

I have created a new theme in Magento 2. This theme has LUMA as it's parent / fallback.

So I want to change the header.phtml file but I don't want to touch the core file so I've enabled paths from the backend so I can find out where the files are.

So, I now have the path to the core file:

```
/home/mydomain/public_html/mage/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
```

Now I want to copy the header.phtml and paste it somewhere in my theme directory?

Well, that is my question ... Where should I place the copy of this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this for footer.phtml, hope should work for header too.

copy file from

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
```

to

```
vendor/[YOUR_NAMESPACE]/[YOUR_THEME]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

File must be moved in the below specified path-

app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

Don't move again inside Vendor Folder.